# Keeping database objects in sync using Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm in the process of creating an Azure Website, and using SQL storage in Azure for database connectivity as well.  If I wanted to follow a simple model of (website instance\database_instance):

TEST - test.website.com\test_database

STAGING - staging.website.com\staging_database

PRODUCTION - website.com\production_database

How would I go about syncing database object from TEST->STAGE->PROD?  On local database, I used to use redgate tools, but I don't know if I can still use those with Azure.

I should add, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with Azure Tools installed.. I'm not sure if there's a database project I can use to promote database objects when I publish as well?'

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Sorry @paqogomez I just marked an answer below, RedGate was the way to go after all.

Comment: Excellent, glad you found your answer. I'll give him a +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you used Red Gate SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare? If so, these should work with SQL Azure so long as you're not using a very old version.

Could you try it and if you come across a problem, let me know, and I'll see what I can do to escalate it.